# Getting the First Letter of a String in Hebrew

Tags: ios, string, swift, character, hebrew

In a UITableView, I'm listing a bunch of languages to be selected. And to put a section index view to the right like in Contacts app, I'm getting all first letters of languages in the list and then use it to generate the section index view.

It works almost perfect, Just I encountered with a problem in getting first letter of some strings in Hebrew. Here a screenshot from playground, one of the language name that I couldn't get the first letter:

[image]

Problem is, the first letter of the name of the language that has "ina" language code, isn't "א", it's an empty character; it's not a space, it's just an empty character. As you can see, it's actually 12 characters in total, but when I get count of it, it says 13 characters because there is an non-space empty character in index 0.

It works perfectly if I use "eng" or "ara" languages with putting these values in value: parameter. So maybe the problem is cause of system that returns a language name with an empty character in some cases, I don't know.

I tried some different methods of getting first letter, but any of it didn't work.

Here "א" isn't the first letter, it's the second letter. So I thought maybe I can find a simple hack with that, but I want to try solving it before trying workarounds.

Here is the code:

```
let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "he")
let languageName = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "ina")!
let firstLetter = first(languageName)!
println(countElements(languageName))
for character in languageName {
    println(character)
}
```

Comment: It seems, the first character is `'RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK' (U+200F)`

Comment: Even if you get the first letter, how are you planning on ordering it vs. other letters? The convention for listing languages is usually to sort using the ISO language code and show the English alphabet as the index.

Comment: That's interesting, I will search about that thanks rintaro. But still I don't understand why this mark is there for just a couple of language name but not all.

Comment: Ian, I'm ordering them first alphabetically and then getting first letters to generate string index. I tried using UILocalizedIndexedCollation, but in that way it prints all alphabet not just the ones in the list. So in this way I think it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet()` to test each character. I can't figure out how to stay in Swift-native strings, but here's a function that uses `NSString` to return the first non-control character:

```
func firstNonControlCharacter(str: NSString) -> String? {
    let controlChars = NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet()
    for i in 0..<str.length {
        if !controlChars.characterIsMember(str.characterAtIndex(i)) {
            return str.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: i, length: 1))
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "he")
let languageName = locale.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: "ina")!
let firstChar = firstNonControlCharacter(languageName)  // Optional("א")
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't explain the weirdness in there, but it solves the problem. It would be nice if anyone can say why it happens.